# A data structure for holding numbers in 2 sets, using BST?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-trees

Design a data structure for holding numbers in two sets:

**Init** - initiate the DS with two empty sets. `O(1)`

**Insert(a,S)** - insert number `a` to set `S` (`S` could be `X` or `Y`). `O(log(n))`. (n is the total number of numbers in the DS)

**Find** - find a number `a` in the DS such that the number of numbers in `X` that are smaller than `a` equals the number of numbers in `Y` that are bigger than `a`, if exists such number. `O(1)`

---

My attempt is using 2 augmented balanced binary search trees, each one presents set `X` or `Y`, insert into it the new number and saving in each node information for finding what is the number of numbers in `X` that are smaller than this node and the number of numbers on `Y` that are bigger than that node.

But given that information how could I implement the `Find` procedure in `O(1)`? Or maybe someone have better design (preferably using augmented BST)?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75804/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44126532/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's your exercise, I don't want to prevent you from finding the solution on your own, but I'll give you some possible hints:

Big hint:

> You can do some work during the Insert operation to make any subsequent Find run fast.

Think about that one for a while.

---

If you're still stuck, here are some more specific hints.  I recommend you think about each one for 15 minutes or more before moving on to the next one.

Hint #2:

> Suppose you wanted to implement an operation InsertAndFind(a,S), that effectively does Insert(a,S) followed by Find().  Could you make that run in O(log n) time?

Hint #3:

> It would also be possible to have a single data structure (e.g., a single augmented balanced binary search tree), with some information in each node.

Hint #4:

> What information would you want to keep in a node, to determine whether that node is something that could be returned in response to a future Find query?

Comment: In each node I can save number of numbers in X that are smaller than this node and the number of numbers on Y that are bigger than that node.
But how can I find which nodes have this two numbers equal in O(logn)? 
And I can I update it?

Comment: @po1son, Good!  You're making excellent progress.  You're on the right track -- you're close.  And those are good questions.  Now go back through all of the hints.  At least one of the hints addresses the two questions in your comment (arguably, two of the hints).  Keep at it!

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: @po1son, keep trying.  It's OK to augment the data structure even further.  If after a few more hours of brainstorming you still can't solve it, you can edit the question to show how far you got and what approaches you considered and why you rejected them.

Comment: in each node `x` keep a pointer to a node in its subtree (rooted at `x`) that has the required property?

Comment: @po1son, this site format doesn't work well for back-and-forth or interactive tutoring.  If you'd like that kind of assistance, I suggest you talk to your instructor or teaching instructor, or find a friend.  I'm afraid this is as much as I can help right now.